# Android HTTP Post no parameters on webserver/ log: GET

Tags: android, http

I´m trying to make an async task from Android to my webserver. But i´m getting no parameters on PHP side. When watching the logfile of my server it´s not a POST but a GET. Why is it a GET and why we are getting no data? Thanks!

```
    public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you add internet permission in manifest file? also check that at server side any header key is available? If it is then you have to use it as a header key.

Comment: Internet permission is set on manifest file. what do i have to set as header key?

Comment: But if is it set to server side?

Comment: no, what do i have set as header key on PHP ?

Comment: Just to be clear, but could you give us a right domain, so I can have a look?

Comment: sorry, that´s not possible. Why is it a GET? i dont´t understand that.

Comment: Problem solved. There was a redirection on server side. Thanks for help!